# BibLaTeX Citetracker Confusion

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing

I have the following requirement: For the **first** time an author / the authors are mentioned, there has to be a **"full"** citation, **matching the entry of the bibliography**. After that, a short form is used, which already works.

Now I found in the [BibLaTeX documentation](http://mirror.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/pub/mirrors/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) the option `citetracker` which I set to true. I also found the macros `\ifciteseen` and `\ifentryseen`. However, I cannot figure out how to use them in my `.cbx` file in order to solve the problem. Do I have to rewrite a macro? And how do I get the bibliography string generated with the help of a `.bbx` file?

If you need more information or find a similar post (in spite of my search), feel free to comment.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{cs.cbx}
\RequireCitationStyle{authoryear}
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
    \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
    \or
    \ifuseprefix
        {\usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#8}}
        {\usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#4}{#6}{#8}}%
    \or
    \usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
    \fi
    \usebibmacro{name:andothers}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[citestyle = cs, bibstyle = standard, backend=bibtex8, citetracker=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
 
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\footcite[S.85]{Knu86}
\lipsum[1]\footcite[S.96]{Knu86}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I want to provide a piece of pseudocode which will hopefully make clear what I mean.

> If the current bib entry (e.g. Knu86) was already cited
>
> (true:) use the citation way defined in the cite style
>
> (false:) print the string from the bibliography

Comment: More information is needed, especially what style you are using.  In general, you should post a minimal example that starts with `\documentclass{...}` and ends with `\end{document}` and only loads the minimal set of packages needed to demonstrate your question/problem.

Comment: @jon: Now you should see both the bibliography entry and the customized citation style.

Comment: Are you trying (more or less) combine how `citestyle=authortitle` (for the first cite) and `citestyle=authoryear` (for subsequent citations) work, where the only significant difference is that the first citation should look like a bibliography entry rather than a normal citation?

Comment: @Jon: Yes, this is correct. However, I would appreciate if I did not need two different BibLaTeX citestyles.

Comment: @PWillms Just adapt the `verbose` citation style or one of its variants. Often it is easier to customize an existing style instead of writing your own from scratch. For example loading biblatex with `citestyle=verbose` and `bibstyle=authoryear` should get you most of the way there.

Comment: See the pseudocode for further explanation. I am afraid that you all seem to misunderstand me.

Comment: I get what you mean, but I don't have time to think about it until tonight.  You need to start with a pre-existing style as was said, and look at how commands like `\cite` and `\fullcite` are defined in the relevant `.cbx` files and go from there.  Basically, what you need (I think) is a `\cite` command that gives a 'fullcite' in the authortitle style or a plain authoryear cite otherwise.  Nothing (yet) in your `cs.cbx` deals with anything related to the issue you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of citation label is already implemented in the `verbose` style and its variants, but with short author-title instead of author-year labels. In `verbose.cbx`, use of the `\ifciteseen` test is demonstrated in the `cite` bibliography macro, defined by:

```
\newbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \ifciteseen
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:short}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}}
```

To obtain the desired output, we can then edit the `cite:short` macro to print `labelyear` in place of `labeltitle`. Full citations are generated by the `cite:full` macro via:

```
\usedriver{\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}{\thefield{entrytype}}
```

which gives the almost same output as the entry's bibliography item, except the name list at the beginning of the entry is printed in the default `first-last` format instead of `last-first/first-last`. Identical output can be obtained with

```
\usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}
```

although the `pages` field may cause some confusion with page references in postnotes. To address this, the `verbose` style and its variants offer an additional option called `citepages`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose,labelyear]{biblatex}

% experiment with these settings
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citepages=omit,citetracker=true}

% replace labeltitle with labelyear
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
  \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}

% full citations same as bibliography
\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}

% from authoryear.cbx
\newbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}{}{%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{labelyear}\printfield{extrayear}}}}

\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill\noindent
Filler text \autocite{baez/article,baez/online}.
Filler text \autocite[85]{bertram}.
Filler text \autocite[96]{bertram}.
Filler text \parencite{baez/article,baez/online}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the `extrayear` field appended to `labelyear` for disambiguation is not incorporated in author-title bibliographies. This field could be added, but an author-year bibliography style would be more reader-friendly. You can achieve this by replacing

```
\usepackage[style=verbose,labelyear]{biblatex}
```

with

```
\usepackage[citestyle=verbose,bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

Comment: OK, the `\printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}}` line was the thing that I actually looked for. Now the general combination of `verbose` and `authoryear` works, although a colon in the bibliography entry is not displayed in the footnote. I will look this up in the next days. Thank you very much!